# Closure Compiler cannot read a directory

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I want to compile some JS files inside a folder using the closure compiler, the issue I am facing is that when I am trying to compile the files in a folder(which contains JS files) whose name has got a whitespace, the closure compiler breaks and cannot recognize the path.
Eg If the folder name that I want to compile is D:\New Folder, it doesn't works but if the name is D:\NewFolder it works.

The exact command I am using to run the closure in command prompt is

`C:\closure-compiler>java -jar compiler.jar D:\New Folder\\*.js --js_output_file D:\Output.js`

But when I run the following command it works

`C:\closure-compiler>java -jar compiler.jar D:\NewFolder\\*.js --js_output_file D:\Output.js`

(Where closure-compiler is the directory which contains the closure compiler jar file).
I am running Closure Compiler on Windows 7 Enterprise and invoking it from the command line.

Is there a way that I* can resolve it?

Comment: What command are you using to compile the files?

Comment: (many) Other programs allow you to specify the path inside parenthesis. I.e `somProgram -someSwitch c:/some path/file.ext` would be a problem as is, and would be re-written as `somProgram -someSwitch 'c:/some path/file.ext'`

Comment: You haven't posted enough information for us to help. It depends on your operating system, whether the compiler is being invoked from the command line or via a build script, etc.

Comment: @Tibos I am using the following command to compile the files       java -jar compiler.jar --js D:\New Folder*.js --js_output_file output.js

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth I am Windows 7 and it gives an error in both cases ie when invoked from command line as well as buildscript

Comment: Have you tried `--js="D:\New Folder*.js"` or even `--js "D:\New Folder*.js"`?

Comment: @Tibos Yeah I have tried both but it doesn't works for me

Comment: @Chad Killingsworth Don't you think its too early to close this topic? The topic was started at Nov20 at 11:48 and was closed at Nov 20 21:44. I think I have replied to my best, against the questions that were put up. I wanted to seek help from the community because was stuck in something, the idea was not to post the question but to resolve it.

Comment: If you want to post the full details of how you are invoking the compiler, including OS, whether it is part of a build step or batch script and the full set of options you are using, I'll vote to reopen the question.

Comment: @Chad Killingsworth I have reframed the question, please can you reopen it now. Do let me know in case the informaton is still insufficient.

Comment: @Ryan Cavanaugh I have reframed the question, please can you reopen it now. Do let me know in case the informaton is still insufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You have more than one issue affecting you:

1. Javascript input files must be specified using the `--js` flag
2. Files must be explicitly specified - wildcards are not currently supported.
3. Directory paths with with spaces must be quoted in Windows.

Here's a corrected version of your command that worked for me in a test environment:

```
java -jar compiler.jar --js "d:\New Folder\input.js"
    --js_output_file D:\Output.js
```

Comment: I tried the same command specified by you but still it gives an error that it cannot read the directory and once the "New Folder" is renamed to NewFolder it works.

Comment: You are executing this from standard windows command prompt, correct?

Comment: Then I would make sure you are using the latest version of the compiler, because I tested that exact command at the windows 7 command prompt and it worked as expected. Batch jobs, other shells (such as cygwin or git bash) may not work in the same way or have different escape characters.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Chad Killingsworth. I am using following version & build number of Closure Compiler
Version : v20131014
Built on : 2013/10/15 09:45
Do I need to use some other version to resolve this ?